# C++ next_permutation without listing in reverse order

Tags: c++, permutation

Is there any way to print all permutations omitting the permutations which already occur in reverse order by using `next_permutation` in C++. For example, after it printed `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, it should not print `{4, 3, 2, 1}`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue. `1,2,3,4` is the first lexicographical permutation, if you use `next_permutation` it will print `1,2,4,3`, not `4,3,2,1`. Perhaps you're asking for [combinations](http://marcodiiga.github.io/permutations-and-combinations/) ?

Comment: Although for Python, the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/960557/2675154) provide some nice explanations.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the first element in a permutation is lexicographically less than the last element, you will not get any permutations that would be duplicate when reversed:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};

do {
    if (v.front() < v.back()) { // first less than last
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the permutations in increasing sequence order you can simply omit any permutation whose last item is less than its first item (its reverse has already been listed).

Since the number of permutation of *n* items is *n*!, eliminating half does not impact on the big-O performance.