# Permutations excluding inverses

Tags: python, permutation

I need to get permutations, excluding mirrored sequences, i.e. (1, 0, 4) should be included, but (4, 0, 1) should be excluded after.
I've came up with the following function but is wondering whether there is simpler solution.

The function skips inverses basing on the fact their last element is the same as the first element of the corresponding sequence, which is already processed given lexicographical order.

```
def permutations_no_inverse(iterable):    
    """Return the half of permutations, treating mirrored sequences as the same,
    e.g. (0, 1, 2) and (2, 1, 0) are the same.
    Assume itertools.permutations returns tuples
    """

    all_perm = it.permutations(iterable)
    cur_start = None 
    starts_processed = set()
    for perm in all_perm:
        new_start = perm[0] 
        if new_start != cur_start:
            if cur_start != None:
                starts_processed.add(cur_start)
            cur_start = new_start
        if perm[-1] in starts_processed:
            continue
        else:
            yield perm
```

Comment: permutation of what please give an input and out value as an example

Comment: @Sumit any iterable, looks like

Comment: Would `(1,2,3)` and `(1,3,2)` be valid in your case? Do you want to exclude _only the inverses_?

Comment: @Idle001 No, in general there are no permutations that are palindromes.   I agree that "inverse" is highly misleading, and would call them "reversed permutation".

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question i thought the tuple itself includes its inverse

Comment: I think itertools orders the inverses automatically in the last columns, try `list(itertools.permutations([1,0,4]))[:len(list(itertools.permutations([1,0,4])))/2:]`

Comment: @Idle001 This only works correctly if the iterable has two or three elements.  For any other number of elements it fails.  (Try e.g. one element or four elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the entries in `iterable` are unique and orderable, I would simply compare any two elements of the permutation (e.g. the first and last one), and only include those permutations where the first element is less or equal than the last element.  This way, you don't need to store what you have already seen, and you don't care in what order `itertools.permutations()` returns the permutations.

Example code:

```
def permutations_no_inverse(iterable):
    for p in itertools.permutations(iterable):
        if p[0] <= p[-1]:
            yield p
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has explicited stated `...wondering whether there is simpler solution`, i think the below one is simple enough:

```
def permutations_no_inverse(iterable):
    found_items = []
    for p in it.permutations(iterable):
        if p not in found_items:
            found_items.extend([p, p[::-1]])
        else:
            yield p
```

Comment: This approach has quadratic runtime, since scanning the list takes linear time.  If the elements in `iterable` are hashable, you can use a set instead of a list to get linear runtime.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The op hasn't stated elements of iterables would be hashable so i can't assume that. Also, your comment is talking about performance when my answer starts clarifying some facts about simplicity, otherwise i wouldn't have used itertools.permutations in the first place and coding a custom function filtering in place. In any case, thanks for a good remark ;)

Comment: You are always making assumptions; the important thing is to state them.  Your code assumes that the iterable has more than one element (for only one element it returns an empty iterable), that the elements in the iterable are unique (otherwise it may return duplicates), and that the elements support `__eq__()` (which holds for almost everything, but still an assumption).

Answer (score 0):

> Based on the fact that python delays the reversed tuple-orderings all for the latest columns, we could envisage the permutations set as a uniform matrix, then divide it diagonally, to get the unmirrored part of the matrix.

```
k=[1,  2, 3,4]
l=itertools.permutations(k)
a=list(l)
b=np.array(a).reshape((len(k),len(a)/len(k),len(k)))
neat_list=np.flipud(b)[np.tril_indices(len(k))]
```

This should be effective with all array lengths I guess ....

With `k=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

This prints

```
array([
   [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
   [5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4],
   [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6],
   [4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5],
   [4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6],
   [3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
   [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5],
   [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6],
   [3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 4],
   [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5],
   [2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6],
   [2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4],
   [2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5],
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
   [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6],
   [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4],
   [1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5],
   [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]])
```

I tried :

```
test=[list(g) for g in neat_list]
any([(u[::-1] in test) for u in test])
```

And this outputs `false` which means no occurence of reversed arrays there.

Comment: The mere fact that no reversed permutations occur in the list does not make this solution correct; the empty list would satisfy this property.  For a six-element list, the result should contain 360 permutations.  Your code only gives 21.  An example of a missing permutation is `1 3 2 4 5 6`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it's because i pulled the upper side of the diagonal, if i choose the lower, it would print all these sub-arrays reversed, which means a reversed  [6 5 4 3 2 1] amongst

Comment: @SvenMarnach i agree there is a mistake in segmentation but this doesn't abort this theory, I'm working on it

Comment: Yeah, it is _possible_ to make something similar work.  However, it's not just a "diagonal" in the usual sense, since the matrix you are dealing with is rectangular.  It's just not worth the trouble, given that there is the dead simple solution given in my answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree with you, this answer is partially wrong, a toddlerstep into linear solution, but all the triangular slice of the matrix satisfies the condition, while there is more solutions outside the diagonal I still fail to locate !

Comment: Where does the quotation come from ?

Comment: @VladimirLenin the basis is obviously clear, [you can see the initiative is already opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960686/4571206), and I'm not gonna take deep researches since the question exists already and not a new thing.