# Limiting permutations using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am writing a tool that is looking to generate all possible pairs of pairs from a list 13 chars long. Each pair must have their second element swapped. i.e. from the list `ABCDEFGHIJKLM` I want to generate pairs such as `AB CD`, `AB CE`, or `CD GK`.

I am using itertools.permutations to do this and it works:

```py
perm_pairs = itertools.permutations(my_list, 4)
```

I am planning on iterating over `perm_pairs` and use the pairs in a seperate program. However, as order is unimportant and the subsequent process has high time complexity, I want to increase efficiency by preventing pair inversions. i.e. if I have already had `AB CD` I do not want to generate `CD AB`.

`itertools.combinations()` does not produce all the required pairs, but `itertools.permeations()` generates 4x more pairs than are required to iterate over.

Is there a "middle way" where I can avoid generating inversions?

Comment: Do you need `AB CD` as well as `BA CD` or why does combinations not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate permutations of a list without "reverse duplicates" in Python using generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960557/how-to-generate-permutations-of-a-list-without-reverse-duplicates-in-python-us)

Comment: Can you give an example of an output that `combinations` doesn't produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `itertools.permutations` for each pair of letters, and then, check if the inverse of pair of pairs doesn't already exist in some set (`perm_pairs`):

```
from itertools import permutations

my_list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM"

perm_pairs = set()

for pair_1 in permutations(my_list, 2):
  for pair_2 in permutations((c for c in my_list if c not in pair_1), 2):
    if pair_2 + pair_1 not in perm_pairs:
      perm_pairs.add(pair_1 + pair_2)
```